# How can I disable Spring Cloud AWS auto-configuration to prevent automatic pickup of AWS credentials?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

How can I prevent Spring Cloud AWS from automatically picking up AWS credentials from the default credentials file (`~/.aws/credentials`) when the application is executed by others on their computers, without their knowledge that it might use these credentials by default?

Upon reviewing the Spring Cloud AWS documentation at https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#credentials, it appears that the only solution is to supply our own `AwsCredentials` and `Region` to override the default behavior. Below is the code snippet I have implemented for this purpose:

```java
@Configuration
public class AwsProviderConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String awsAccessKeyId;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretAccessKey;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider customAwsCredentialsProvider() {
        return StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey));
    }

    @Bean
    public AwsRegionProvider customRegionProvider() {
        return () -> Region.of(awsRegion);
    }

}
```

Despite implementing this solution, I still observe logs indicating that the application is attempting to read profiles from the credentials file. The relevant log entries are as follows:

```
2024-01-28T11:45:54.746-07:00  INFO 54870 --- [app] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2024-01-28T11:45:54.869-07:00  WARN 54870 --- [app] [           main] s.a.a.p.internal.ProfileFileReader       : Ignoring profile 'xxxxxxxxxx' on line 1 because it did not start with 'profile ' and it was not 'default'.
2024-01-28T11:45:55.103-07:00  WARN 54870 --- [app] [           main] s.a.a.p.internal.ProfileFileReader       : Ignoring profile 'xxxxxxxxxx' on line 1 because it did not start with 'profile ' and it was not 'default'.
2024-01-28T11:45:55.103-07:00  WARN 54870 --- [app] [           main] s.a.a.p.internal.ProfileFileReader       : Ignoring profile 'xxxxxxxxxx' on line 1 because it did not start with 'profile ' and it was not 'default'.
2024-01-28T11:45:55.104-07:00  WARN 54870 --- [app] [           main] s.a.a.p.internal.ProfileFileReader       : Ignoring profile 'xxxxxxxxxx' on line 1 because it did not start with 'profile ' and it was not 'default'.
2024-01-28T11:45:55.105-07:00  WARN 54870 --- [app] [           main] s.a.a.p.internal.ProfileFileReader       : Ignoring profile 'xxxxxxxxxx' on line 1 because it did not start with 'profile ' and it was not 'default'.
```

Could someone please advise on how to completely disable the auto-configuration of Spring Cloud AWS and ensure that it does not attempt to use credentials?

Comment: It also looks like the file it's actually reading has invalid content.

Comment: @jarmod I've modified the `default` profile in my local credentials file to `xxxxx`. This ensures that the application won't automatically pick up the `default` profile by default.

Comment: Where are the AWS credentials actually going to come from? If you don't want the behavior of the Spring Cloud DefaultCredentialsProvider (which is basically a passthrough to the AWS Java SDK default credentials provider, as far as I can tell) then you'll have to override its default behavior or supply and configure a [custom credentials provider](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#custom-awscredentialsprovider) that can do whatever you want.

Comment: @jarmod I believe that is what I'm doing with `AwsProviderConfiguration` class

Comment: Do you know for sure that your custom code is actually loaded and executed? Does it execute before or after the logs you've shown with ProfileFileReader?

Comment: @jarmod Indeed, it retrieved the values from my configuration file (`application.yaml`). During debugging, I observed that it invoked `AwsProviderConfiguration` before logging the output of `ProfileFileReader`.